# C Read text from file and put it into array

Tags: c, arrays, file

I'm using C and trying to read text from file and store it in array for later use but it doesn't seem to work. It also doesn't give an error. What is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    char rida[120], str[100];
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", str[i]) != EOF)
    {
        rida[i] = str[i];
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

data.txt file contains the following:

```
Text
Text2
Text3
Text4
Text5
```

Comment: `str[i]`, really? What did your compiler tell you?

Comment: You're getting individual characters and strings (arrays of characters) a bit mixed up.

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: and assigning of one string to an another is an error

Answer (score 1):

Change `rida[120]` to something like `rida[20][120]` because it seems you want to store each word on its own,so you need two dimensional array.Also use `strcpy()` to copy strings,and not the assignment operator `=`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    char rida[20][120], str[100];
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", str) != EOF)
    {
        strcpy(rida[i], str);
        i++;
    }
    size_t n;
    for (n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
        printf("%s\n", rida[n]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: maybe the last for loop you've entered is for testing purpose, i guess. anyway correct answer +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the answer using command line arguments:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
    {
        FILE *fp;
        if(argc<2) return printf("Error.Not enough arguments.\n"),1;
        if((fp = fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL) return printf("Error. Couldn't open the file.\n"),1;
        char str[10][100]={""}; //Making sure to have only the scaned strings in the array
        int i=0;
        while ( fscanf(fp,"%s",str[i++]) != EOF);

        int j=0;
        while(j<i){
        printf("%s\n",str[j++]);
        }

        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
```